# how to select a particular null value from the table containing null values

Tags: oracle11g

how to select  a particular null value from the table containing null values

Comment: Assuming 3NF/BCNF, what differentiates these NULL columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can select on the other columns, but of course all `NULL` values are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is null` .

For example , `select * from tableA where columnA  IS NULL` will select all the rows from table A which columnA  has a null value.